# Uncaught ReferenceError: RSVP is not defined , error while using require.js with rsvp

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, rsvp.js, rsvp-promise

I am working on a demo showing the error handling in promises using **rsvp.js**. Everything seemed fine, till I used the CDN url for rsvp.js in a  tag. Now since I have require.js for module loading in my application, I tried loading the rsvp.js module via require js  syntax. In the Chrome network tab, I see the rsvp.js module getting loaded properly as well, but I get the below  error in console,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: RSVP is not defined.

```
require(["bootstrap","js/rsvp"], function(bootstrap,rsvp) { 
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getEmployeeDetails() {
        var radioValue1 = $("input[name='option1']:checked").val();
        var requrl;
        if (radioValue1 == "fail") {
            requrl = "../../../testservice/getEmployeeIdss";
        } else {
            requrl = "../../../testservice/getEmployeeId";
        }
        return new RSVP.Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            $.ajax({
                url: requrl,
                success: function (response) {
                    try {
                        $('#successBoard').append("<b> <i> Ajax Call 1 Succeeded! </i>  </b><br/>" + "Employee ID:" + response.stuId + "<br/>");
                        resolve(response.stuId);
                    } catch (e) {
                        reject(e);
                    }
                },
                error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                    console.log('Ajax 1 failed : Rejecting Promise 1');
                    $('#errorBoard').append("<b> <i> Ajax 1 failed : Rejecting Promise 1</i>  </b><br/>");
                    reject(thrownError);
                }
            });

        });
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took a look at the [source code of RSVP](https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/blob/master/lib/rsvp.umd.js) and found this code:

```
/* global define:true module:true window: true */
if (typeof define === 'function' && define['amd']) {
  define(function() { return RSVP; });
} else if (typeof module !== 'undefined' && module['exports']) {
  module['exports'] = RSVP;
} else if (typeof platform !== 'undefined') {
  platform['RSVP'] = RSVP;
}
```

The first `if` is where RSVP detects that it is running in an AMD environment and registers as an AMD module. So you won't have a global `RSVP`.

Now, in your code you require RSVP and bind it to the `rsvp` variable, all lowercase. So it is accessible as `rsvp`, not `RSVP`. Either refer to it as `rsvp` or change the variable name in the function you pass to `require` so that it is `RSVP`:

```
require(["bootstrap", "js/rsvp"], function (bootstrap, RSVP) {
```

Note that there's no point in having a reference to Bootstrap because it installs itself as a jQuery plugin, so you could do:

```
require(["js/rsvp", "bootstrap"], function (RSVP) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You havent defined `RSVP`, you have included the rsvp libraray but set it to the variable `rsvp` and not `RSVP`, so when you call `RSVP.Promise()` it throws the error.
Basic usage via - https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js/-

```
var RSVP = require('rsvp');
var promise = new RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){});
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried the solution you have given, now its resolving RSVP properly but I am getting the below exception "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Promise' of undefined" on the line,
 return new  RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

Comment: Its not resolving RSVP if its reading it as undefined. Have you tried defining it within the `$(document).ready(){};`? as in the edit above